# Springboot project giving 404 not found on elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-404, war

What are the possible reasons for 404 not found on elastic beanstalk. I run my war file locally and /home brings me to my index.jsp with no problems but when the war is deployed to my aws environment I download the logs and everything looks to be running good, but when I go to the environment/home it gives me a 404 not found and the logs look like the controller maps to index.jsp but don't find the file. Thanks.